# "He interrupted neither with his name"

Tags: meaning

*Boom —Boom —Popolac walked, the noise of its steps receding to the east. Popolac walked, the hum of its voice lost in the night. After a day, birds came, foxes came, flies, butterflies, wasps came. Judd moved, Judd shifted, Judd gave birth. In his belly maggots warmed themselves, in a vixen’s den the good flesh of his thigh was fought over. After that, it was quick. The bones yellowing, the bones crumbling: soon, an empty space which he had once filled with breath and opinions.
Darkness, light, darkness, light. **He interrupted neither with his name**.*

http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/72065/7/Barker_-_Books_Of_Blood_Vol_1.html

I would like to ask whether "neither" in my sentence is connected to the nouns "darkness" and "light". So he did not interrupt either "darkness" or "light". Our official translator translated the passage as if the original was "He interrupted (bother) not even with its name".

Comment: I think your interpretation is correct.  *Neither* implies alternatives: not this or that.  Since two things were just mentioned - darkness and light - it's reasonable to assume that it means "neither darkness nor light".

Comment: @Stangdon - You should post that as an answer.  Complicated text, complicated syntax, good question - simple answer.

Comment: Compare *I saw two people, but I spoke to neither.* As with your example, you can assume that *neither = neither **of them*** ("they" being two previously-mentioned things; in OP's case, *light* and *darkness*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absent a **nor** phrase, we must understand **neither** to refer back to two earlier nouns.

Answer (score 1):

The word *neither* is used in relation to two things or people. It means *"not either"*; not one or the other.  In the sentence, there are two things 
 i.e. *darkness* and *light*.  In order to refer to them again,  we have used the *neither* as a pronoun.

So there's nothing wrong with the sentence:

> He interrupted neither with his name.